# Dependency confusion while installing Doctrine Migration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to install `doctrine-migrations-bundle` and I'm getting a *Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages*, here is the log

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.  

  Problem 1  
   - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.9  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.8  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.7  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.6  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.5  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.4  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.3  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.2  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.1  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC2  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC1  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA4  
   - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master.  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA3  
   - Installation request for symfony/config dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony/config dev-master, symfony/symfony dev-master, symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev.  
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA2  
   - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.1.0,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.1.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.2, symfony/symfony v2.1.3, symfony/symfony v2.1.4, symfony/symfony v2.1.5, symfony/symfony v2.1.6, symfony/symfony v2.1.7, symfony/symfony v2.1.8, symfony/symfony v2.1.9, symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/symfony v2.2.1, symfony/framework-bundle 2.1.x-dev, symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8, symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony 2.2.x-dev.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.0-RC3, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony v2.2.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1.  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle 2.1.x-dev|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-BETA2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0-RC3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1  
   - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony 2.1.x-dev, symfony/symfony v2.1.0, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA2, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA3, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-BETA4, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC1, symfony/symfony v2.1.0-RC2, symfony/symfony v2.1.1, symfony/symfony v2.1.2, symfony/symfony v2.1.3, symfony/symfony v2.1.4, symfony/symfony v2.1.5, symfony/symfony v2.1.6, symfony/symfony v2.1.7, symfony/symfony v2.1.8, symfony/symfony v2.1.9.
```

Here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "isoft/mssql-bundle": "master-dev",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/config": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    }
}
```

I never understood `composer` log.

Can someone help me to decipher the error so I can see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issue today trying to install `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`. I will leave my answer here because, although the solution is simple, I have not found it elsewhere.

Just like we need `doctrine/orm` to have `doctrine/doctrine-bundle`, we need **`doctrine/migrations`** to have `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle`.

So, include it also in your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't require `symfony/config` `dev-master` *and* `symfony/symfony` `2.1`, because the main package replaces the others. If you change `symfony/config` to `2.1.*` it might work out better.

Comment: I changed it, but it still brings this big kind of log. Do you see something else that could be wrong ?

Comment: The output says that sonata-project/admin-bundle requires symfony 2.2, and you are requiring 2.1. If you change all the sonata-project/* requirements to `2.1.x-dev` instead of `dev-master`, then you'll get the right version for symfony 2.1, and everything installs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've now been able to fix this kind of errors with [packagist](https://packagist.org/)